# Postgresql - increment counter in rows where a column has duplicate value

Tags: postgresql

I have added a column (seq) to a table used for scheduling so the front end can manage the order in which each item can be displayed. Is it possible to craft a SQL query to populate this column with an incremental counter based on the common duplicate values in the date column?

Before

```
------------------------------------
| name | date_time           | seq |
------------------------------------
| ABC1 | 15-01-2017 11:00:00 |     |
| ABC2 | 16-01-2017 11:30:00 |     |
| ABC1 | 16-01-2017 11:30:00 |     |
| ABC3 | 17-01-2017 10:00:00 |     |
| ABC3 | 18-01-2017 12:30:00 |     |
| ABC4 | 18-01-2017 12:30:00 |     |
| ABC1 | 18-01-2017 12:30:00 |     |
------------------------------------
```

After

```
------------------------------------
| name | date_time           | seq |
------------------------------------
| ABC1 | 15-01-2017 11:00:00 | 0   |
| ABC2 | 16-01-2017 11:30:00 | 0   |
| ABC1 | 16-01-2017 11:30:00 | 1   |
| ABC3 | 17-01-2017 10:00:00 | 0   |
| ABC3 | 18-01-2017 12:30:00 | 0   |
| ABC4 | 18-01-2017 12:30:00 | 1   |
| ABC1 | 18-01-2017 12:30:00 | 2   |
------------------------------------
```

Solved, thanks to both answers.
To make it easier for anybody who finds this, the working code is:

```
UPDATE my_table f
    SET seq = seq2
    FROM (
        SELECT ctid, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY date_time ORDER BY ctid) -1 AS seq2
        FROM my_table
        ) s
    WHERE f.ctid = s.ctid;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) `row_number()`:

```
with my_table (name, date_time) as (
values

('ABC1', '15-01-2017 11:00:00'),
('ABC2', '16-01-2017 11:30:00'),
('ABC1', '16-01-2017 11:30:00'),
('ABC3', '17-01-2017 10:00:00'),
('ABC3', '18-01-2017 12:30:00'),
('ABC4', '18-01-2017 12:30:00'),
('ABC1', '18-01-2017 12:30:00')
)

select *, 
    row_number() over (partition by name order by date_time)- 1 as seq
from my_table
order by date_time;

 name |      date_time      | seq 
------+---------------------+-----
 ABC1 | 15-01-2017 11:00:00 |   0
 ABC1 | 16-01-2017 11:30:00 |   1
 ABC2 | 16-01-2017 11:30:00 |   0
 ABC3 | 17-01-2017 10:00:00 |   0
 ABC1 | 18-01-2017 12:30:00 |   2
 ABC3 | 18-01-2017 12:30:00 |   1
 ABC4 | 18-01-2017 12:30:00 |   0
(7 rows)
```

Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46648071/1995738) for a similar question about *updating existing records with a unique integer.*

Comment: This provides the numbers, how do I update the table with these numbers?

Comment: How could I increment counter when the values DON'T duplicate (i.e., the opposite case) ?

Comment: @igorkf - please ask a new question with sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [ROW_NUMBER()](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-row_number/).

```
SELECT name, date_time, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY date_time ORDER BY name) FROM [table]
```

Comment: That displays the numbers very nicely but it does not populate the new column.

Comment: This returns the following error:
ERROR:  relation "t" does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE t set seq = seq2 FROM (

Comment: Turns out my UPDATE statement does not work in PostGres (but it does work in SQL Server). Your table needs a primary key to update, or you can do something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/6578705/1933308

Comment: thanks, I used ctid as per the link that klin provided